# ZF2: getting user session_id

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need to get session_id() in ZF2? Using `session_id()` won't return any value. I tried `Zend_Session::getId()` but it didn't work, probably because I haven't included the path (which I don't know).

Can anyone help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: for zf2 session, please read this : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html

Answer (score 1):

`session_id()` should work, but the correct way would be to access it from the session manager, e.g. (from a controller):

```
$sessionManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Session\SessionManager');
$id = $sessionManager->getId();
```

If neither of these are returning a value for you then there's another problem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to use zend session container in your page that is.

```
   use Zend\Session\Container;
```

now create an object of container by following.

```
    $session = new Container('User');
```

now set value $userid or any other variable in session by following object.

```
   $session->offsetSet('userId', $id);
```

now you can get it by following code.

```
    $user_id=$session->offsetGet('userId');
```